# Understanding contra/covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

From Hehl and Obukhov's Foundations of Classical Electrodynamics:

> A transformation from a basis $e_\alpha$ of $V$ to another one $e_{\alpha '} = (e_1', \dots, e_n')$ is described by a matrix $L:= ({L_{\alpha '}}^\alpha) \in GL(n,\Bbb R)$: $$e_{\alpha '} = {L_{\alpha '}}^\alpha e_\alpha.$$  The corresponding cobases are thus connected by $$\vartheta^{\alpha'} = {L_\alpha}^{\alpha '}\vartheta^\alpha,$$ where $({L_\alpha}^{\alpha '})$ is the inverse matrix to $({L_{\alpha '}}^{\alpha})$, i.e., ${L_\alpha}^{\alpha '}{L_{\alpha '}}^{\beta} = \delta^\beta_\alpha$.  Symbolically, we may also write $e' = Le$ and $\vartheta' = (L^T)^{-1}\vartheta$.  Here $T$ denotes the transpose of the matrix $L$.

I understand that the matrix multiplying $\vartheta^\alpha$ must be the inverse of the one multiplying $e_\alpha$ because

$$\vartheta^{\alpha'}(e_{\alpha'}) = \vartheta^{\alpha'}({L_{\alpha'}}^\alpha e_{\alpha})= {L_{\alpha'}}^\alpha\vartheta^{\alpha'}(e_{\alpha})=1 \\ \implies {L_{\alpha'}}^\alpha\vartheta^{\alpha'}=\vartheta^{\alpha}$$

So to get rid of the ${L_{\alpha'}}^\alpha$ on the left we'd have to multiply by its inverse.

But in the last line of that section it claims that this matrix should also be the *transpose*.  Where does that come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix should be transposed if you want to apply it on the left to a column vector. Look at the indices of the summation. In the first equation you list, the second index is summed over. In the second equation you list, the sum is over the first index. The first situation is left multiplication of a matrix by a column vector, while the second is right multiplication by a row vector, or equivalently left multiplication of the transpose by a column vector.